# how can I populate data(in a consistent way) in an angular application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, frontend

In my application I can retrieve the data successfully from the backend and show it on the frontend.
But sometimes when I navigate from other pages, I do see the data. Sometimes I don't. I have to refresh the page to see the data.

This is a part I want to populate:

```
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <mat-form-field>
                                        <mat-label>Client WhatsApp Number</mat-label>
                                        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="clientWhatsAppNumber"
                                                    (ngModelChange)="searchWhatsAppSendReceiveMessages()">
                                            <mat-option [value]="" (click)="goToFirstPage()">All</mat-option>
                                            <ng-container *ngIf="isAdmin(); else isNotAdmin">
                                                <mat-option *ngFor="let whatsAppClientNumber of filteredWhatsAppNumbers"
                                                            [value]="whatsAppClientNumber" (click)="goToFirstPage()">
                                                    {{ whatsAppClientNumber }}
                                                </mat-option>
                                            </ng-container>
                                            <ng-template #isNotAdmin>
                                                <mat-option *ngFor="let whatsAppChildClientNumber of whatsAppChildClientNumbers"
                                                            [value]="whatsAppChildClientNumber" (click)="goToFirstPage()">
                                                    {{ whatsAppChildClientNumber }}
                                                </mat-option>
                                            </ng-template>
                                        </mat-select>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
```

'filteredWhatsAppNumbers' is populated every time. The problem is populating 'whatsAppChildClientNumbers'.

This is where I retrieve and filter the numbers:

```
    constructor(
        private whatsAppSendReceiveMessagesService: WhatsAppSendReceiveMessagesService,
        private whatsAppClientNumberService: WhatsAppClientNumberService,
        private whatsAppNumberService: WhatsAppNumberService,
        private clientService: ClientService,
        private helperService: HelperService,
        private systemUserService: SystemUserService,
        private reportService: ReportService) {
        this.whatsAppSendReceiveMessages = [];
        this.whatsAppSendReceiveMessage = new WhatsAppSendReceiveMessages;
        this.pageSize = 5;
        this.currentPage = 0;

        const currentDate = new Date();
        for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            this.availableMonthYears.push(new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth() - i, 1));
        }

        this.selectedMonthYear = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), 1);

        this.getAllClientWhatsAppNumbers();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loadSystemData();
        this.onMonthYearSelected();
    }

    loadSystemData() {
        this.currentUserSubscription = this.systemUserService.getCurrentLoginUser().subscribe(resp => {
            this.currentUser = resp;
            console.log("Logged in: ", resp.role)
            if (this.currentUser != null) {
                if (this.currentUser.role === 'Sysadmin') {
                    this.getAllClients();
                } else {
                    this.getCurrentClient();
                }

                this.getAllChildClientWhatsAppNumbers();
                this.getAllParentClientNumbers();
                this.searchWhatsAppSendReceiveMessages();
            }
        });
    }

    isAdmin() {
        return this.currentUser?.role === 'Sysadmin';
    }

    getAllClients(): void {
        this.clientService.getAllClients().subscribe(
            response => {
                if (response) {
                    this.clients = response;
                    console.log("Clients: ", this.clients)
                }
            }, error => this.helperService.showNotification('top', 'right', 'danger', error.error ? error.error : "Something went wrong")
        );
    }

    getCurrentClient() {
        this.clientSubscription = this.clientService.getForCurrentLoginUser().subscribe(client => {
            this.client = client;
            this.clientRef = client.clientRef;
            this.getChildClients();
            this.clientSubscription.unsubscribe();
        })
    }

    getChildClients() {
        this.clientService.getChildClients(this.clientRef, this.currentPage, this.pageSize, this.searchString)
            .subscribe(responsePage => {
                this.clients = responsePage?.content;
            });
    }

    getAllClientWhatsAppNumbers() {
        this.getWhatsAppClientNumberSubscription = this.whatsAppClientNumberService.getAllWhatsAppClientNumbers().subscribe(resp => {
            this.whatsAppClientNumbers = resp;
            this.updateFilteredWhatsAppNumbers();
            this.getWhatsAppClientNumberSubscription.unsubscribe();
        })
    }

    updateFilteredWhatsAppNumbers() {
        const matchedClient = this.clients?.find(obj => obj.parentClient !== null && obj.clientRef === this.clientName);

        if (this.clientName && matchedClient) {
            this.filteredWhatsAppNumbers = this.whatsAppClientNumbers
                .filter(clientWhatsAppNumber => clientWhatsAppNumber.clientConfig?.clientRef === matchedClient?.parentClient?.clientRef)
                .map(clientWhatsAppNumber => clientWhatsAppNumber.whatsAppNumber?.number);
        } else if (this.clientName) {
            this.filteredWhatsAppNumbers = this.whatsAppClientNumbers
                .filter(clientWhatsAppNumber => clientWhatsAppNumber.clientConfig?.clientRef === this.clientName)
                .map(clientWhatsAppNumber => clientWhatsAppNumber.whatsAppNumber?.number);
        } else if (this.clientName === '' || this.clientName === 'ALL' || !this.clientName) {
            this.filteredWhatsAppNumbers = this.whatsAppClientNumbers
                .map(clientWhatsAppNumber => clientWhatsAppNumber.whatsAppNumber?.number);
        }
    }

    getAllChildClientWhatsAppNumbers() {
        this.whatsAppChildClientNumbers = [];
        this.whatsAppClientNumbers.forEach(whatsappClientNumber => {
            if (whatsappClientNumber.clientConfig.clientRef === this.currentUser?.client?.clientRef) {
                this.whatsAppChildClientNumbers.push(whatsappClientNumber.whatsAppNumber.number);
            }
        })
    }
```

I have tried calling the 'getAllClientWhatsAppNumbers()' ngOnInit but I was getting errors.
I expected that every time I navigate to the page. The 'mat-option' is populated.

Comment: This line `this.getAllClientWhatsAppNumbers();` should be moved out of the constructor, and into `ngoninit`. What errors do you get?

Comment: @nsquires 'this.whatsAppClientNumbers' is undefined under 'getAllChildClientWhatsAppNumbers()'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a race condition.

This function, `getAllChildClientWhatsAppNumbers` (synchronous) is executing before `whatsAppClientNumbers` is properly hydrated.

Without refactoring a bunch of code, the simplest "fix" is to move `getAllChildClientWhatsAppNumbers()` after this line `this.whatsAppClientNumbers = resp;`

like this:

```
    getAllClientWhatsAppNumbers() {
        this.getWhatsAppClientNumberSubscription = this.whatsAppClientNumberService.getAllWhatsAppClientNumbers().subscribe(resp => {
            this.whatsAppClientNumbers = resp;
            this.getAllChildClientWhatsAppNumbers()
            this.updateFilteredWhatsAppNumbers();
            this.getWhatsAppClientNumberSubscription.unsubscribe();
        })
    }
```

and to move this to `ngOnInit`

```
getAllClientWhatsAppNumbers
```